# rvm 1.10.1 can't set a gemset as default

Tags: ubuntu, rvm

I have 3 gemsets

```
 $rvm gemset list

   gemsets for ruby-1.9.2-p290 (found in /home/railsu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290)
   global
   rails31
   rails311
```

then I run

```
$rvm use 1.9.2@rails311 --default
Using /home/railsu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290 with gemset rails311
$rvm current
ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311
$rails -v
rails 3.1.1
```

It looks good,but:

```
 $rvm default
 $rvm current 
 ruby-1.9.2-p290
```

There is not rails311 gemset in default. 
I try this on other user which rvm's version is 1.8.6,and it work.I get

```
$rvm default
$rvm current
ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I get the answer. When I install rvm

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

I lose -s stable

```
bash  < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```